# Tasker: How to disable profile while phone is locked

Tags: tasker, google-now

guys, I have started using Tasker,and I absolutely love it.

I figured out I could write a recipe for me to start Google Now bt simply shaking the phone, and it worked.

One problem, though. If the phone is locked and the display is off, shaking the phone won't start the app, obviously, but if the phone is locked but the display is on - in lock screen -  if I shake the device, it won't unlock, fortunately, but I hear the Google Now beep,and as soon as I unlock my phone, Google Now is there, open, and I have to cope with constant beeping while I'm running listening to music,or receiving a whatsapp text (what makes the display on while it's locked sometimes), and I always have to close the Google Now app, cause it will launch as soon as I unlock my phone, even if I accidentally shook the device even when it's locked.

What I want to do is have this profile disabled when the phone is locked, regardless of wether the screen is on our not. I have explored all the apparent solutions, and I have come to a conclusion that it can probably only be solved with a var (which I can't write).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fairly simple solution that does not require the use of a variable.

You will need to set up two additional profiles and also ensure that you name the profile you created to trigger on your shake context.  To name your existing profile, if you haven't already, long press on the profile and then touch the A on the top bar to name it - let's use 'Google Shake' for this example.  In order to control the status of a profile through a task action it must have a name.

The first new profile you need will trigger on Display Off.  The associated task should set the Profile Status (find this under Tasker in actions) of your Google Shake profile to Off.

The second new profile you need will trigger on Display Unlocked (rather than Display On).  This will ensure that it only runs when the device is actually unlocked rather than the display turning on and remaining on the lock screen.  The associated task should set the Profile Status of your Google Shake profile to On.

That's it!  Test it out.  Note that it may take a second or two for the Google Shake profile to be turned off and on when the two triggers happen so don't shake too quickly after turning the display off and/or unlocking it.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to help. You can indicate that the answer worked and is accepted by checking it.